# Why are my bash commands in notepad++ not printing in the command prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new at writing bash files to open into the virtual command prompt. I have been trying to print the username, current date, and a list of all users currently running processes on my computer. I have been using notepad++. The error occurs in the

```
whoami="$users" 
echo 'Good day to you,' "{$users}"
```

by printing `{ }` and also with the

```
echo 'These are a list of users who are currently running processors on this computer: '
echo "{$ps}"
```

This also prints `{ }`. What do I need to do to allow these to print correctly?

[image: NotePad++ code image]

[image: Results in the command promt]

Comment: Please do not post code and text output as images or links to images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: Need to do `$()` to run a command and capture its output. That is `$(users)` and `$(ps)`.

Comment: `$users` and `$ps` are variables that need to be set before you can use them.

Comment: How do you expect `whoami="$users"` to get the user's name?

Comment: And if you're assigning the variable `whoami`, why are you printing `$users`?

Comment: You seem to understand how to set a variable to the output of a command, since you did it correctly for `$now`. You should do the same things for your other variables.

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to Notepad++. Are you run the _bash_ window using the "Run" command of Notepad++ (F5)? In any case, your screenshot says that your variables `users` and `now` are not set. You need to put them into the environment before running the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
#Set current user
user=$(whoami);
echo 'Good day to you,' $user

#Set Date
current_date=$(date);
echo 'Today is ,' $current_date

echo 'These are a list of users who are currently running processes on this computer'

echo $(ps -A)
```